# mb_convert_encoding() not working on accented letters

Tags: php

I want to convert an array with accented characteres from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8, but when i try to convert the uppercase letters, it dont work, whats should i do?

The loop works with the lowercase letters, when it reachs the uppercase ones it bugs out, there's something missing here?

The problem its that my database have some especial characteres on it and i want to replace them with utf-8 characteresç

My code:

```
$normal = array(
'á',
'â',
'à',
'å',
'ä',
'ð',
'é',
'ê',
'è',
'ë',
'í',
'î',
'ì',
'ï',
'ó',
'ô',
'ò',
'ø',
'õ',
'ö',
'ú',
'û',
'ù',
'ü',
'ç',
'Á',
'Â',
'À',
'Å',
'Ä',
'Ð',
'É',
'Ê',
'È',
'Ë',
'Í',
'Î',
'Ì',
'Ï',
'Ó',
'Ô',
'Ò',
'Ø',
'Õ',
'Ö',
'Ú',
'Û',
'Ù',
'Ü',
'Ç'
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($normal); $i++) {
    $especial = mb_convert_encoding($normal[$i], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
    echo $especial . PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
Ã¡
Ã¢
Ã 
Ã¥
Ã¤
Ã°
Ã©
Ãª
Ã¨
Ã«
Ã­
Ã®
Ã¬
Ã¯
Ã³
Ã´
Ã²
Ã¸
Ãµ
Ã¶
Ãº
Ã»
Ã¹
Ã¼
Ã§
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
Ã
```

Comment: For this to work, you need to save your PHP source code as `ISO-8859-1`. If you're using UTF-8, there's nothing to convert. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My database lost their charset and all accent characters became especial, so i am updating all collumns from all tables to change the especial characters for normal ones.

Comment: Since your question doesn't have anything to do with databases, I'll assume it's a preliminary test. As such, it doesn't really provide any information. The encoding of PHP string literals depends on the encoding of the source code file, unless you explicitly assign the binary values.

Comment: i will try to change source code charset to see if can solve like you mentioned above

Comment: it worked, after i change the default charset to iso, the mb_convert_encoding($normal[$i], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'); had to be done the oposite, changing iso-8859 to utf-8. Can you answer so i can close the question?